# Console Jump and Run in C#

Tags: c#, console-application

I want to code a easy Jump and Run inside a console with C#. Something like supermario just without monsters. When I want to update the "player" its not always working or flashing.

```
        static int cursorX = 5;
        static int cursorY = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(cursorX, cursorY);
            Console.Write("A");

            while(true)
            {
                MovePlayer();
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        private static void MovePlayer()
        {
            if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
            {
                updateCursor(cursorX + 1, cursorY);
            }
            else if(Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
            {
                updateCursor(cursorX - 1, cursorY);
            }
        }

        private static void updateCursor(int x, int y)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write("A");
        }
}
```

Comment: This is not enough detail for us to help you moving forward, show us what you've tried, what are the results and what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want a character like a letter "A" moving on a map with objects to jump over inside a console. But the problem is that the character is not always moving or the console flashes without doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your character "A" is not moving because `cursorX + 1` and `cursorX - 1` will not assign new value (cursor position) to it self. It just adds `+1` and substracts `-1` from its current value. You need to assign new value to `cursorX`. You need to use `Increment operator (++)` and `Decrement operator (--)`.

```
private static void MovePlayer()
{
    if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
    {
        updateCursor(cursorX++, cursorY);
    }
    else if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
    {
        updateCursor(cursorX--, cursorY);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check current "A" character cursor position with specific object cursor position. If both are same than collided.

Comment: Please give it a try by yourself and then ask another question with issue which you faced. SO it not for developing everything for you.